# Windows Silverlight Phone 8.1 Tmp Files

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8, memory-management, local-storage

```
await tablex.ExistsAsync();
await tablex.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null);
```

When I run this two code within the Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app,each time it runs it creates 2 mb "XCP***.tmp" file in local folder and they remain until app is closed, so after a while app consumes whole local memory of phone since this codes repated when page refresh.Is that because of silverlight or my mistake?

All method(When I debug it only above two codes cause tmp file creation):

```
private async Task<List<Message>> query(Person x)
    {

        List<Message> msgs = new List<Message>();

        StorageCredentials credential = new StorageCredentials("", "");
        // Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(credential, false);


        // Create the table client.
        CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

        //Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
        CloudTable tablex = tableClient.GetTableReference(person.getId().Replace("@", "").Replace(".", ""));
        bool exist = await tablex.ExistsAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        GC.Collect();
        if (exist)
        {

            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, !!!!YOU!!!!!!)
            // Construct the query operation for all customer entities where PartitionKey="".
            string filter1 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, x.getId());
            string filter2 = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("ToWhomSend", QueryComparisons.Equal, x.getId());
            string finalFilter = TableQuery.CombineFilters(filter1, TableOperators.Or, filter2);
            TableQuery<ConversationEntity> query = new TableQuery<ConversationEntity>().Where(finalFilter);
            if (query != null)
            {
                ///!!!TMP!!
                TableQuerySegment<ConversationEntity> cone = await tablex.ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync(query, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
                GC.Collect();

                List<ConversationEntity> convEnt = sortMessages(cone);
                for (int i = convEnt.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                {
                    if (msgs.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Message msg = new Message();
                        msg.setMessage(convEnt[i].Message);
                        msg.setWhoSend(convEnt[i].PartitionKey);
                        msg.setToWhomSend(convEnt[i].ToWhomSend);
                        msg.setDate(convEnt[i].RowKey);
                        msgs.Add(msg);
                    }
                    else if (msgs.Count == person.getFriends().Count)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        bool found = false;
                        for (int j = 0; j < msgs.Count; j++)
                        {
                            if ((convEnt[i].PartitionKey.Equals(msgs[j].getToWhomSend()) && convEnt[i].ToWhomSend.Equals(msgs[j].getWhoSend()))
                                || (convEnt[i].PartitionKey.Equals(msgs[j].getWhoSend()) && convEnt[i].ToWhomSend.Equals(msgs[j].getToWhomSend())))
                            {
                                found = true;
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                        if (!found)
                        {
                            Message msg = new Message();
                            msg.setMessage(convEnt[i].Message);
                            msg.setWhoSend(convEnt[i].PartitionKey);
                            msg.setToWhomSend(convEnt[i].ToWhomSend);
                            msg.setDate(convEnt[i].RowKey);
                            msgs.Add(msg);
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        return msgs;
    }
```